# install 'rdflib' on online jupterlab over browser

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

I'm new to jupyterlab, I run it on my browser.
While I'm adding Sparql code, I tried to import rdflib; However, it shows me an error saying ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rdflib'.
I need help of how to make rdflib works on online JupyterLab

Comment: Try `import sys` and then `!{sys.executable} -m pip install rdflib`.

Comment: HTH: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/#How-to-use-Pip-from-the-Jupyter-Notebook